# Can you help me with physics lab calculations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

My question is, how do you find the torque of a rotating spool with a connected string being pulled down by its hanging mass?

So in this experiment we had a machine with two rotating discs, one on top of the other, and as we spin a disc, the machine counts how many of 200 lines on the edge of the disc pass through a sensor per second. In other words, it calculates the angular speed based on those lines. Then through calculation we can calculated the angular speed in radians through equation 2pi * counts per second/200. 
So in one part of this experiment we had to drop a ball down a ramp and have it be caught in a catcher attached to the top of the disc. This would set the disc rotating and thus we would determine the angular velocity and momentum caused by the initial speed/momentum of the ball. However, before setting it so we had to determine the moment of inertia, I, of the disc/ball catcher complex and this here is where I am confused. See, what we did was we attached a spool to the bottom of the disc which has a string attached to itself, and on the other side of the string was a hanging mass. We wound up the string and let the mass drop, and we noted the counts by the machine as they changed every two seconds. And from these we were supposed to determine the angular acceleration caused by the mass on the disc. And using the acceleration we were to determine the moment of inertia. This is where I am stuck. From what I discovered, I am supposed to find the torque of the spool using its radius and the mg of the mass (T=R*F), which I am then to equate to the equation T=A * I and find the I. Is this correct??

Than you for any help you can provide. I apologize for writing a whole book.

Comment: I lost interest before the third line of text.  Take this as constructive advice:  get to the "punch line" early; phrase your question succinctly and *then* provide the details as an elaboration.  And, for gosh sakes, use *a lot more white space*.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and here's my "punch line:" In this experiment we had to find the moment of inertia of a disc by having a it connected to a spool attached to a string with a hanging mass on the other end. Basically the string was wound up around the spool and it was allowed to drop. Then the machine recorded the velocity of the disc every second. Am I correct in assuming that I am supposed to find the torque of the spool using its radius and the mg of the mass (T=R*F), which I am then to equate to the equation T=A * I and find the I. Is this correct??

Comment: Wrong. $T=\alpha I$, where $\alpha$ is the ANGULAR acceleration.

Comment: Right. That is what I meant. My question is, how do you find the torque of a rotating spool with a connected string being pulled down by its hanging mass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation in the question and the explanation in your comment seem to be at odds with each other. I will arbitrarily pick to explain the experiment described in your comment.

You have string wrapped around a disc free to rotate. The other end of the string is attached to a ball which is allowed to fall. You measure the orientation of the disc as a function of time $\theta(t)$, the radius of the spool, and the mass of the ball.

From $\theta(t)$, you can find the acceleration of the ball (I will leave it to you to find out how).

From the acceleration on the ball, you can find the net force on the ball.

Since the only two forces acting on the ball are gravity and tension, you can deduce the tension force.

Since you know the radius of the spool and the tension force, you know the torque.

Since you know the torque and the angular acceleration, you know the moment of inertia.

Comment: I apologize if my question is unclear or makes no sense. I'll attribute that to my poor writing. I'll try to give it another shot: the spool was screwed unto the top disc and had a mass attached to it via a string. The disc was allowed to rotated freely as the mass unwound itself due to gravity, and fell to the floor. From this, we were to determine acceleration. But how do I find the torque of the mass to the spool? Is it the tension * the radius from the spool? If so how do I find the tension?

Comment: ok I did interpret your question correctly. Read my answer and if you have a question about my answer, ask.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was a bit confused when I first read your answer, but now I get what you're saying. Just one question, though, is the angular acceleration of the spool equal to the downwards acceleration of the mass. If not, how is it related to it then?

Comment: No, in fact simple dimensional analysis rules out the possibility of equality. Let me ask you this. If the angular orientation of the spool changes by $\theta$ how much does the position of the mass change? Differentiate this relation twice with respect to time to get the relationship between the linear acceleration of the block and the angular acceleration of the spool.

Comment: Am I meant to do this manually through the set up or theoretically through math? I am not exactly sure how I would do it in either case but the former would be impossible, as I do not have access to the experimental set up. The only information that I have, as obtained from experiment, is the angular acceleration of the disc, the radii of both the spool and the disc, and the weight of the mass. How would I determine the linear acceleration of the mass, or more importantly the moment of inertia of the disc, from any of this information?

Comment: You said the only thing you didn't get was the relationship between angular acceleration of the spool and the linear acceleration of the weight. To get this relationship think about how there is an inextensible string connecting outside of the spool to the wieght. Then a certain angular displacement of the spool will cause a certain linear displacement of the weight.

Comment: I understand that a certain amount of angular displacement will cause a certain amount linear displacement. There will be a certain ratio. I get it. But how to find this ratio, I do not get. Because I did not measure any angular displacement as it corresponds to linear displacement when I did the experiment. Please tell me how I am to find this ratio, is there any general equation that relates the two?

Comment: If the spool goes around a full revolution (an angle of $2 \pi$) how far does the mass fall (i.e. how much string is fed out)?